Как добавить в параметры запуска игры в стим,Запуск другой програмы
Тоесть чтобы во время открытия,Програмы А открывалась и програма B.

Попробуйте оптимизировать запуск программ с помощью .bat файла и создания ярлыка для него с кастомизацией и прочими фишками, пример тут

я использую батник для фермы в кс2 там запуск стима в тихом режиме тоист сам стим неоткривается после авторизации сразу запускается нужное приложение с моими парамитрами
